# Django JSon response format, nested fields

Tags: python, json, ajax, django

I just made an ajax request to a DJango View, it give me back the data, but i don't know how to get only the fields that i want.

This is the part of my view:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        txt_codigo_producto = request.POST.get('codigobarras_producto') 
        response_data = {} 
            resp_producto=Producto.objects.all().filter(codigobarras_producto=txt_codigo_producto)
            resp_inventario=InventarioProducto.objects.all().filter(producto_codigo_producto__in=resp_producto).order_by('-idinventario_producto')[:1]
            resp_precio=Precio.objects.all().filter(producto_codigo_producto__in=resp_producto,estado_precio=1).order_by('-idprecio')[:1] #

            response_data['codprod']=serializers.serialize('json', list(resp_producto), fields=('codigo_producto')) 
            response_data['inventario']=serializers.serialize('json', list(resp_inventario), fields=('idinventario_producto'))
            response_data['nombre']=serializers.serialize('json', list(resp_producto), fields=('nombre_producto'))
            response_data['valorprod']=serializers.serialize('json', list(resp_precio), fields=('valor_precio'))

            return HttpResponse(
                json.dumps(response_data),
                content_type="application/json"
            )
```

"json" is the name of the array that I get as response from the view, I send it to the console, as this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
```

And i get this:

```
{"codprod":"[{\"model\": \"myapp.producto\", \"fields\": {}, \"pk\": 1}]",
    "nombre":"[{\"model\": \"myapp.producto\", \"fields\": {\"nombre_producto\": \"Pantal\\u00f3n de lona \"}, \"pk\": 1}]",
    "valorprod":"[{\"model\": \"myapp.precio\", \"fields\": {\"valor_precio\": \"250.00\"}, \"pk\": 1}]",
    "inventario":"[{\"model\": \"myapp.inventarioproducto\", \"fields\": {}, \"pk\": 1}]"}
```

I tried this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(json.codprod));
```

With that I get this:

```
"[{\"model\": \"myapp.producto\", \"fields\": {}, \"pk\": 1}]"
```

But if I try something like `json.codprod.pk` or `json.codprod[0]` or `json.codprod["pk]` I get `undefined` in the console.

I want to know how to acces to those fields, in "valorprod" I want the "valor_precio" value, so it must be "250.00", in "nombre" I want the value of "nombre_producto" it must be "Pantal\u00f3n de lona".

Hope you can give me a hint. I think this is a JSON syntax problem, but I'm new with this.

---

Following `Piyush S. Wanare` and `Roshan` instructions, I have made some changes on the view:

```
    resp_producto=Producto.objects.filter(codigobarras_producto=txt_codigo_producto)
            resp_inventario=InventarioProducto.objects.filter(producto_codigo_producto__in=resp_producto).order_by('-idinventario_producto')[:1].only('idinventario_producto') 
            resp_precio=Precio.objects.filter(producto_codigo_producto__in=resp_producto,estado_precio=1).order_by('-idprecio')[:1].only('valor_precio') 
            resp_productonombre=Producto.objects.filter(codigobarras_producto=txt_codigo_producto).only('nombre_producto')
            resp_productocodigo=Producto.objects.filter(codigobarras_producto=txt_codigo_producto).only('codigo_producto')

            response_data = {'codprod': resp_productocodigo,'inventario':resp_inventario,'nombre':resp_productonombre,'valorprod':resp_precio}
    return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(list(response_data)),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
```

But I get empty fields in the console:

```
["nombre","valorprod","codprod","inventario"]
```

---

Another edit, and the code that worked:

I used the views as they was at the beginning, with the double encoding, I just deleted the "codprod" part, but I wrote this on the ajax response code:

```
var res_valorprod=JSON.parse(json.valorprod);
var res_inventario=JSON.parse(json.inventario);
var res_nombre=JSON.parse(json.nombre);
var campos_valorprod =res_valorprod[0].fields;
var campos_nombre =res_nombre[0].fields;
console.log(res_nombre[0].pk);
console.log(campos_valorprod.valor_precio);
console.log(res_inventario[0].pk);
console.log(campos_nombre.nombre_producto);
```

This is working, I get what I want, but if you know something better to acces to the multiple nested JSON fields, I will be glad to know it. User `dsgdfg` gave me a hint.

Comment: You are double-encoding your JSON - first in `serializers.serialize` and then in `json.dumps`...

Comment: Use `JSON.parse(incoming_data)` before calling any item. A warning: You can't move AJAX answer to outside. Need some html source for `undefined` or `not answered` or `not loaded` or `not converted`.

Comment: don't convert your response_data to list, write json.dumps(response_data).

Comment: @VikasVerma That was my first try, but I got 
500: TypeError at /Buscar/Producto/
[<Producto_Deferred_codigobarras_producto_codigoesdbb633e0f57ad11fbc667f2a916b5fb4: 1||VT-70522||Pantalón de lona >] is not JSON serializable

... Thats why I used that. That string is the one that I defined in my `__str__` function, on the model.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing multiple encoding, i.e. first you using serializers.serialize and then json.dumps.

Use only json.dumps and content_type as json like this, without using serializers.

```
response_dict = {'your_data_key': 'and your values'}
return HttpResponse(
                json.dumps(response_data),
                content_type="application/json"
            )
```

and then in client side you are not required to do **JSON.stringify(json.codprod)** .

As you sent **content_type='application/json'**, it parse response as json.

```
console.log(resp.your_data_key); #will print proper response yor data values.
```

Comment: Could you check my edit? I am not using JSON.stringify anymore. And thank you for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your first question:-
You can change your queries as follows:

```
resp_producto=Producto.objects.filter(codigobarras_producto=txt_codigo_producto).only('requiredField')
resp_inventario=InventarioProducto.objects.filter(producto_codigo_producto__in=resp_producto).only('requiredField').order_by('-idinventario_producto')[:1]
resp_precio=Precio.objects.filter(producto_codigo_producto__in=resp_producto,estado_precio=1).only('requiredField').order_by('-idprecio')[:1]
```

## Then serialize it.

```
response_data['codprod']=serializers.serialize('json', list(resp_producto), fields=('codigo_producto')) 
            response_data['inventario']=serializers.serialize('json', list(resp_inventario), fields=('idinventario_producto'))
            response_data['nombre']=serializers.serialize('json', list(resp_producto), fields=('nombre_producto'))
            response_data['valorprod']=serializers.serialize('json', list(resp_precio), fields=('valor_precio'))
```

## Suggestion:- It will be better if you create single {} by iterating through each required objects and create list [{},{}] rather than serializing it, and dump it as you have done like,

```
return HttpResponse(
                json.dumps(response_data),
                content_type="application/json"
            )
```

Then at FrontEnd you should use JSON.parse(responceData) for indexing over it.

Comment: I have tried, but I thing something is wrong, I edited my answer. Hope you can help. And thankyou for your previous help :D

Comment: Just use `json.dumps(response_data)`. I am sure this is problem of serializing data. Or try to `serializers.serialize('json',response_data)` and then `json.dumps(response_data)`.

Comment: I found something, I have defined a `__str__` methond on every model, and when I use the "only" filter, thats what I get, the `__str__` not the required field, I made the queries on the Shell, and this was the result: `[<InventarioProducto_Deferred_anaquel_idanaquel_idab783c00ae45d85daee6edd04e321cba: 1 - P: 1||VT-70522||Pantalón de lona  - F: 2016-07-30 18:21:13+00:00 >]`